# File sharing app via Cloud Storage

Tags: dropbox, google-drive-api, dropbox-api, onedrive, cloud-storage

I was looking for a file sharing cloud storage solutions.
My requirements are below
1. Should be able to share contents to limited users(Or public availability)
2. Users should be able to download the contents from the shared folder to their private cloud storage.

Many cloud storage services like Dropbox, Google Cloud Storage, amazone, Microsoft azure allows public folders, but is there an option to copy the public shared content to the users private cloud storage area without any copying to a third party server?

Also is it possible to copy contents from on service provider to other service provider without any third party server?(eg: From Dropbox to Google Drive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at Cloudberry Explorer? It let's you copy from public to public cloud (e.g. Amazon to Constant) or public to private cloud (e.g. Amazon to Cloudian).  It is fairly intuitive and inexpensive.